# How to implement tf.assign in PyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to convert a Tensorflow network to Pytorch, and I found there is a tensorflow function called `tf.assign` that I didn't know how to implement in Pytorch. The Source code:

```py
# normalization and clip to positive operations
v_gp = tf.reshape(self.v, [self.num_grid, self.num_grid, self.num_group, self.block_size])
v_gp_norm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(v_gp, axis=-1) / np.sqrt(self.num_group)
v_norm = tf.reshape(v_gp_norm, [self.num_grid, self.num_grid, self.grid_cell_dim])
self.norm_grads = tf.assign(self.v, tf.stop_gradient(v_norm))

self.clip_v = tf.assign(self.v, tf.stop_gradient(tf.clip_by_value(self.v, 0, np.inf)))
```

`self.v` is a trainable variable with shape `(self.num_grid, self.num_grid, self.grid_cell_dim)`

I try to implement by set `tensor.data`, is this right?

```py
self.v.data = ((F.normalize(self.v.reshape(self.num_grid, self.num_grid,self.num_group, self.block_size), dim=-1) /np.sqrt(self.num_group)).reshape(self.num_grid, self.num_grid, self.grid_cell_dim)).data
```